# Custom setter for foreign key attribute for Mongoid using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

In my rails app, have a tree-like model like this:

```
class File
  belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "File"
end
```

I want to add functionality to the behavior of the parent setter. So something like this (except it doesn't work)?

```
def parent=(new_parent)
  super(new_parent)
  # Additional stuff I want to do here
end
```

I need the default behavior to still exist since I think it manages the relations but I need to know when parent is changed so I can do some additional tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I currently have is this:

```
class File   
  belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "File"   
  before_save :check_parent

  def check_parent
    if self.parent_id_changed?
      # Additional stuff I want to do here
    end   end end
```

The only downside is you have to save for this to kick in. Ideally I would want it to kick in as soon as parent_id is changed. Otherwise this works just fine though I'd be open to a better solution.